# Grails i18n and link tag anomaly

Tags: grails, internationalization, grails-2.0, taglib

I am experiencing what I can only describe as an anomaly with i18n in Grails 2.5.5.

I have a menu bar as follows;

```
<div id="mainMenu" class="mainMenu">
    <g:link controller="dashboard" class="myClass">
        <g:message code="mainmenu.dashboard.text"/>
    </g:link>
    <g:link controller="news" class="myClass">
        <g:message code="mainmenu.news.text"/>
    </g:link>
    <g:link controller="reports" class="myClass">
        <g:message code="mainmenu.reports.text"/>
    </g:link>
    <g:link uri="/contact" class="myClass">
        <g:message code="mainmenu.contact.text"/>
    </g:link>
</div>
```

All works ok in an alternative language to the default (English) until you click on the single uri driven tag link (contact) in which case all of the i18n labels revert to English.

I’m just wondering if anyone has ever experienced this strange behaviour before?

Comment: I suspect you need to include `params="[lang: params.lang]"` to preserve the locale when using the `uri` option.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Will give it a try.